# Problem with dependencies in Streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit

When I try to run my streamlit app I get these errors in Anaconda Prompt:

[image]

I simplified the code to be more readable, but basically it process an input with a Keras model, then I save this model with pickle in order to make predictions afterwards with Streamlit API

```
import streamlit as st 
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os 
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
import joblib
import pickle



def some_function():

     pass  #some function to preprocess data and train a model with Keras

    
def main():
  ruta_to_model=r'path'
  model = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(ruta_to_model,'model_pose.pkl'),'rb'))

  st.set_page_config(page_title='Pose Framework',layout='wide',initial_sidebar_state='expanded')



  files=[]

  for file in os.listdir(r'path'):
      if file.endswith('.jpg'):
          files.append(file)

  option=st.multiselect('Input:', files)

  if option and st.button('Predict'):
      inputs=some_function()
      model.predict(inputs)
```

Comment: I think the error is somewhere in `some_function()`, in your preprocess function

Answer (score 0):

The error contains

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DataFrame' from 'pandas' (unknown location)
```

Have you installed `pandas` inside your conda environment?

```sh
conda install pandas
```